# How can I solve Google My Business Duplicate location problem?

Tags: google-my-business

I have managed two google my business accounts (locations). These two locations are of my clients. These two locations are not duplicate. Google mark one of them duplicates and merges the content of both locations. Now, What can I do?
If re-activation is not possible then I want to secure my that location back which googles mark as duplicate. Let me have two locations A and B. Google marks location A as duplicate and merges all reviews of A to B. Now B is live and A is not live. With showing a message for A (This location is a duplicate of a location that's already on Google. Delete either this location or the location already in your account.
). I want location A to be active not B. What can I do now?